# What is the difference between using round braces “()” and not using it in instance declaration of php?

Tags: php

I see some people use braces "()" when creating a new instance of a class using `new`. Some do not.

Is there any difference?

Comment: No difference if they are empty. Reason is they can be omitted if so. They are only required if you want to hand over arguments, then you do need them for syntactical reasons.

Comment: You can enforce using `new` with braces using https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/2.3/src/Fixer/Operator/NewWithBracesFixer.php.